# Using a specific transform on GeoPandas 'to_crs' function

Tags: python, geopandas, pyproj

I have a GeoDataFrame with CRS `epsg:4326` and want to convert to `epsg:32066`

Such as:

`gdf.to_crs(epsg=32066)`

I know that GeoPandas is selecting the optimal transformation and it works.
But I want to specify which Transformation code it should use. Is this possible?

I have attempted to do this with Pyproj by specifying the transformation:

```
transform_step1 = Transformer.from_pipeline("EPSG:15851")
transform_step1.transform(-84.81629793076491, 24.233538817965595, direction="INVERSE")
```

But I want to know if it is possible to specify the transformation code in the `.to_crs()` method.

Comment: https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not currently possible, but has been discussed in the past: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1175